# How to increase memory usage when running Nightwatch

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

When running Nightwatch tests I typically just run it like this:

```
nightwatch --test tests/file.js
```

I'm currently getting an error that looks like this:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory
    1: node_module_register
    2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
    3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
    4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString
    5: v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::IsNumberStart
    6: 0000028B313843C1
```

I was looking up fixes and it seems node requires more memory in this scenario.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 nightwatch --test tests/file.js
```

How should I rewrite the above line to make it work?

EDIT:

I've also tried:

```
npm install -g increase-memory-limit
increase-memory-limit
```

and also tried updating the package.json by adding:

```
"scripts": {
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5"
}
```

Comment: Are you perchance running parallel processes?

Comment: How would I check?

Comment: I guess you could use something like `ps` and look at how many node processes are being spawned. I'm not sure about this, but nightwatch may even spawn an external node process for non-parallel processing. Hopefully my answer shows how to increase the memory limits globally for you. Also, are you sure you aren't also exceeding the 8GB limit you set?

Comment: Ah, I see. I only have the one node process. I haven't yet been able to test it with a different memory limit other than the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nightwatch may not be passing along the memory limits in any processes it spawns. You can set node options with environment variables, however. That should take effect for any spawned node processes:

```
npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=8192" nightwatch --test tests/file.js
```

Comment: If you're using `npm`, you can use `npx` to execute things installed in `node_modules` that aren't in your path. Updated. But inside of your `package.json` scripts, the `npx` isn't needed since you have `cross-env` installed as a dependency.

Comment: I'm currently running now. Will see if it can finish successfully without the memory error.

Comment: It seems to be going well. Typically it would crash around 140 / 8600 but it's passed that and it's up to 220 / 8600.

Comment: When I first ran it I got: 

 npx: installed 1 in 1.989s
 Path must be a string. Received undefined
 npx: installed 10 in 2.034s

Do you know what "Path must be a string. Received undefined" is for?